# Continuous version of ergodic with integral

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T}^n)$ such that $f \geq 0$ and $f$ might have a singularity, but along some curve or line $\xi(t): \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{T}^n$ the value $f(\xi(t))$ is defined and continuous, can we say that
$$
\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f(\xi(s))ds = \int_{\mathbb{T}^n} f(x)\;dx? 
$$
or, at least saying that
$$
\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f(\xi(s))ds \leq C?
$$

The situation I have in mind is $\xi(t) = (x,\sqrt{2}x)$, and the function is
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\sin(2\pi x) - \sin(2\pi y)}}
$$
for example. I know that if $f\geq \varepsilon >0$ and $f$ is continuous then by approximation with trigonometric polynomial one obtains a positive answer. However, I have no clue if this remains true in this situation.